# Where to set catch-all address in Postfix (virtual mailboxes in affect)

Tags: linux, postfix

I successfully configured Postfix to deliver messages to virtual mailboxes.

I can set aliases and pipes inside /etc/postfix/virtual and mailboxes inside /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox files.

However, whenever I set a catch-all domain and point to a remote email address, it overrides all other virtual mailboxes and virtual aliases set in postfix. How can I set a catch-all forwarding to the remote email address when virtual mailbox is enabled?

I set catch-all like this:

```
@mydomain.com     catchall@otherdomain.com
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The catchall should be in the `virtual_alias_maps` file (in your case `/etc/postfix/virtual`) and *not* in the `virtual_mailbox` file.

Take a look [here](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html), search the page for `Mail forwarding domains` and you'll find this example:

```
1 /etc/postfix/main.cf:
2     virtual_alias_domains = example.com ...other hosted domains...
3     virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
4 
5 /etc/postfix/virtual:
6     postmaster@example.com postmaster
7     joe@example.com        joe@somewhere
8     jane@example.com       jane@somewhere-else
9     # Uncomment entry below to implement a catch-all address
10     # @example.com         jim@yet-another-site
11     ...virtual aliases for more domains...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I already tried adding @domain.com to my /etc/postfix/virtual table but once it's added, it overrides all other aliases and captures all emails.

Comment: @Cem actually the manual says `the examples shows how one would implement a catch-all virtual alias that receives mail for every example.com address *not listed* in the virtual alias file`. So it should work. Have you done `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` after the modifications?

Comment: @Cem but where is your config?

Comment: As @MrShunz says, "for every example.com address *not listed* in the virtual alias file". This was what caught me out. It seems that the `@example.com target@example.net` syntax is only intended for use with true mail-forwarding domains; that is, domains for which *all* email is forwarded to one or more other domains. This means that e.g. if you have `alice@example.com`, `bob@example.com`, and `catchall@example.com`; and you want other `*@example.com` mail to be sent to `catchall@example.com`, then you need to specify "redundant" aliases for `alice` and `bob` ...

Comment: ... i.e. add the entries `alice@example.com alice@example.com` and `bob@example.com bob@example.com` to your `virtual_alias_maps` map. Honestly quite disappointing, and I am yet to find an alternative, simpler configuration for this use case, if one even exists.

Answer (score 0):

To us the simplest solution was giving THREE entries for virtual_alias_maps, *they are executed in order until the first match* eg.

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
virtual_alias_maps = 
    hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, 
    proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/virtual_mail_exist_maps.cf, 
    hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_after_ldap
```

The first entry is a 'classic' local file virtual, it may forward from .com to .net domain if you need something like this, eg.

```
/etc/postfix/virtual:
    @mydomain.com @mydomain.net
```

The second entry is a database, sql or ldap or anything else. When an account matches, postfix serves **exactly the mail it was queried for** and exits here - successfully forwarding the mail to more or less itself (postfix logic :))

```
/etc/postfix/ldap/virtual_mail_exist_maps.cf
     server_host     = x
     server_port     = x
     ...
     result_format   = %s
```

The third entry is another simple local file. Postfix will do lookups here only if the database lookups do not succeed, here you can place your catch-all address

```
/etc/postfix/virtual_after_ldap
    @mydomain.net postmaster
```